# In sufficient balance exception

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bankaccount{
    double diposit, withdraw;
 double balance=0;
 public Bankaccount(double balance)
 {
     this.balance=balance;
 }
  void deposit(double ammount)
{
       Scanner b=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("diposit a amount");
     ammount=b.nextInt();
     balance +=ammount;
}
 void withdraw(double ammount)
{
       Scanner b=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("withdraw a amount");
     ammount=b.nextInt();
     balance +=ammount;
}

  void display()
  {
      System.out.println(balance);
  }
public static void main(String[]args)
{


}}
```

How to display these conditions in main function? I have already created one exception for this for insufficient balance. I want to throw the exception here.

Comment: can you reframe your question? whats the actual issue?

Comment: I did'nt see any conditions there  ???

Answer (score 1):

Use this to throw an exception.

```
throw new InsufficientBalanceException();
```

And declare the method as

```
void withdraw (double amount) throws InsufficientBalanceException
{
    if (amount > balance)
        throw new InsufficientBalanceException();
    else
        balance -= amount;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you withdraw you must subtract the amount not add it but first you must check if you can subtract that amount:

```
void withdraw(double ammount) throws InsuffcientBalanceExeption
{
    Scanner b=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("withdraw a amount");
    ammount=b.nextInt();
    if(balance<amount){
       throw new InsuffcientBalanceExeption();
    }
    balance -=ammount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class DebitException 
{ 
    static void fun() throws IllegalAccessException 
    { 
        double balance = 0, damount, wamount;

        Scanner dep=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Deposit an amount");
        damount=dep.nextInt();
        balance += damount;

        Scanner wd=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Withdraw an amount");
        wamount=wd.nextInt();
        balance -= wamount;


        if (balance<0)
        {
        throw new IllegalAccessException(); 
        }
        else
        System.out.println(balance);
    }



    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 

        try
        { 
            fun(); 
        } 
        catch(IllegalAccessException ex) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Exceeding Balance"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

You can use this code... This code will work 100%...